# How to create a dataframe where the value comes from the results of a function with many variables? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

By running the following code through santiment API, i get the dataframe of bitcoin price.

```
san.get(
    "prices/bitcoin",
    from_date="2018-06-01",
    to_date=datetime.now(),
    interval="1d")
```

And the "bitcoin" string in the above code comes from another dataframe "slug" column which is acquired by the following code:

```
import san
san.ApiConfig.api_key = '365oqzfjhgsmuhkp_7dedsnrghiialdpq'
from datetime import datetime

df=san.get("projects/all")
```

I want to create a new dataframe which includes all the cryptocurrency price with the name coming from  df["slug"]  column. Therefore, i can get a dataframe of all the cryptocurrency price.

Can anyone kindly help me with this problem ?   Really appreciate!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxMlm.png)

Answer (score 0):

First do:

`df=san.get("projects/all")`

To create new DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_new=pd.DataFrame()
df_new['names_bitcoin']=df['slug']
```

To add colums of Bitcoin DataFrame:

`df_new['new_col_name']=bitcoin['name_of_colum_to_add']`

Example

`df_new['price']=bitcoin['priceUsd']`

If you want add index off Bitcoin DataFrame:

`df_new.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(bitcoin.index.values.tolist()))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for not describing my question clearly. But what i want to generate a new dataframe including all the cryptocurrency in df["slug"] column. I have attached a screenshot. –

Comment: Was it what you were looking for?

Comment: Not exactly, as the image attached. I want to generate a new dataframe which includes all the cryptocurrency's prices. The cryptocurrency names are in the df["slug"]. Appreciate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already a `dataframe` called for example `'df1'` with the prices and `df2` with the bitcoin string in `'column1'`.  Add a column to `df1` with the bitcoin string.

```
df1['slug']=df2['column1']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what i want to generate a new dataframe including all the cryptocurrency in df["slug"] column.  I have attached a screenshot.